# How to move a Google Cloud Web App into production?

Tags: makefile, cloud, make.com

I have a problem using *Make* (previously *Integromat*). I created a Google Restricted connection to a Google Drive. It is made through an Oauth 2.0 request made by an Web App that I created inside the Google Cloud Console. Now every week I need to log in to Make to reauthorize that connection because my App is not a trusted App..
The message say:

> Google hasn’t verified this app. You’ve been given access to an app that’s currently being tested. You should only continue if you know the developer that invited you.

Now I understand that I need to move this App from testing into Production but I can't find how to do it!

Does any one here know how?

Answer (score 0):

### Moving a Cloud Web App into production

Go to your cloud console and make sure the project involved is selected from the dropdown.
Then using the navigation menu, go to **APIs and Services > OAUTH consent screen**.
In the publishing status section, the **PUBLISH APP** button can be found.

If your app uses [restricted or sensitive scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/13463073) you'll need to perform extra steps to verify your app.

> Apps that request access to scopes categorized as sensitive or restricted must complete Google's OAuth app verification before being granted access.

[Console cloud OAUTH consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk1Ft.png)